# show that $ϕ(n/d)=g(d)$ where $ g(d)=\# \{a \in \{1,\dots ,n\} | GCD(a,n)=d\}$

Tags: number-theory

This is a homework question and I am to show that
$$ϕ(n/d)=g(d)$$
where $g(d)$ is the number of $\{a \in \{1,\dots,n\}|\, GCD(a,n)=d\}$

I have justified earlier that the sum over all divisors $d$ of $n$ of $g(d)=n$. I am wondering if I need to express n now as a product of prime powers, and work out $ϕ(n)$? I am looking for hints, and I will post up my solution when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,n)=d$, then $a$ divides $d$, so you may as well consider only the numbers $a=d\cdot k,1\le k\le n/d$. But $(k,n/d)=(a,n)/d=1$...

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that for every $b<n/d$ that's relatively prime to $n/d$, there is an $a<n$ with $\gcd(a,n)=d$ and vice-versa. Basically, construct a bijection. As a hint if $\gcd(b,n/d)=1$ then consider what $\gcd(bd,n)$ is.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ (a,n)=d\iff (a/d,n/d)=1,\, $ hence the map $\ x\mapsto dx\ $ yields a bijection

$$ \{a\in [1,n]\ :\ (a,n)= d\} \leftrightarrow \{ a\in [1,n/d]\ :\ (a,n/d)=1\} $$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.

I have now that 
"If $(a,n)=d$, then $a$ divides $d$, so you may as well consider only the numbers $a=d⋅k,1≤k≤n/d$. But $(k,n/d)=(a,n)/d=1$"

$ϕ(n/d)$=the number of integers in ${1..(n/d)}$ which are co-prime to $n/d$.

Now,
$g(d)=\#\{dk ∈ \{1,..,n\}| (k,n/d)=1\} = \#\{k ∈ \{1,..,n/d\}: (k,n/d)=1\}$
i.e. $g(d) =$ the number of integers in ${1..(n/d)}$ which are co-prime to $n/d = ϕ(n/d)$

Comment: By the way, my answer was meant as a hint; I don't advise using it verbatim in your homework. The key, as others have pointed out at this point, is that multiplication by $d$ is a bijection from the numbers coprime to $n/d$ and less than it to the numbers less than $n$ and with GCD equal to $d$.